# Draw a model modifying its center of mass

Tags: c#, model, xna, mesh

I'm creating a 3D game with XNA, and I'm stuck when I try to attach correctly a weapon to a bone.
You can see the result below :

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeEl5.jpg)

So, the weapon follow the right hand, I just need to find a good rotation but this is not my problem.
My problem is : When I scale down the machete, its Y value decreases... Indeed, I think that XNA sets the position thanks to the center of mass of the mesh... I wanted to know if is it possible to modify this center of mass ? to draw my machete from the handle (I don't know if we can say that in this context).
I hope you will understand what my problem is :)
I apologize for my bad english, see you :)

Comment: Are you sure that the origin point of the model isn't the center of mass. I'm not sure how you have it set up but I know I would re-position the vertices of the model so the origin was somewhere near the handle.

Answer (score 0):

When drawing the weapon you should do few matrix multiplicatins.
1) places the blade in center origin
2) resizes it
3) rotates it against local axis
4) places the blade in the wanted location.
The order of the multiplication matters! Multipliying in a different order will yield anoying results and displacements of the model.
Matrix transform = fixPosMat * Matrix.Scale(1.5f) * rotationMat * PositionMat;

Comment: Ok sorry ! I get it ! :D I think it's ok. Thank you so much, see you guy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand...
I draw my model thanks to this matrix :

```
            boneLocal = Matrix.Invert(skinnedModel.SkeletonBones[index].InverseBindPoseTransform)
                        * animationController.SkinnedBoneTransforms[index]
                        * Matrix.CreateScale(scale)
                        * _rotation 
                        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(_position);
```